# ViewPager2 does not restore state after fragment resumes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I use ViewPager2 to create a Horizontal Scrollable layout. Now when an item of ViewPager2 is clicked a CustomTab intent is launched to load a URL, on Exiting the CustomTab Screen ViewPager2 malfunctions, the parent layout takes the height of the whole screen, and the content of ViewPager2 disappears, Also the same fragment also contains a Linear Recylerivew which works fine. I am unable to diagnose the problem.

Here is a brief view of problem

[image]

**fragment_courses.xml**

```
<FrameLayout 
    style="@style/parent.contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/tickinsidecircle" />
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   />
                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/normalPadding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/normalPadding"
                    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/normalPadding" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/question_posts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_question_post" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**FragmentCourses.java**

```
package com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.fragments;



public class FragmentCourses extends Fragment implements MatchCourseClickListener, PostClickListener {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "FragmentCourses";

    FragmentCoursesBinding binding;
    private FirestoreScorecardViewModel scorecardViewModel;
    private QuestionPost questionPost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    private void loadCourses(UserScorecard scorecard) {
        CollectionReference coursesRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COURSES);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions < MatchCourse > courses = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder < MatchCourse > ()
            .setQuery(coursesRef, MatchCourse.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner()).build();

        CourseAdapter courseAdapter = new CourseAdapter(courses, getContext(), this);
        binding.viewPager.setAdapter(courseAdapter);
        binding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        int nextItemVisiblePx = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_next_item_visible);
        int currentItemHorizontalMarginPx = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin);

        binding.viewPager.setPageTransformer(new SnappyPageTransformer(nextItemVisiblePx, currentItemHorizontalMarginPx));
        binding.viewPager.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalMarginItemDecoration(
            requireContext(), R.dimen.viewpager_current_item_horizontal_margin_testing,
            R.dimen.viewpager_next_item_visible_testing));

        binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        });

    }
```

**item_viewpager**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewCourse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shopperCardBacground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_nelson"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cantidad_cursos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_participants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/android_developer" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fake_course_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And the last part of Puzzle **CourseAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.increaseyouriq.databinding.ItemShopCardBinding;
import com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.listeners.MatchCourseClickListener;
import com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.model.MatchCourse;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class CourseAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter < MatchCourse, CourseAdapter.ViewHolder > {
    private final MatchCourseClickListener matchCourseClickListener;

    public CourseAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions < MatchCourse > options, Context context, MatchCourseClickListener listener) {
        super(options);
        this.matchCourseClickListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ItemShopCardBinding itemShopCardBinding = ItemShopCardBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemShopCardBinding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MatchCourse model) {
        holder.binding.cardViewCourse.setOnClickListener(view - > matchCourseClickListener.onScrollPagerItemClick(model));
        holder.setData(model);
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemShopCardBinding binding;

        ViewHolder(ItemShopCardBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void setData(MatchCourse matchCourse) {
            binding.tvParticipants.setText(String.valueOf(matchCourse.getNumberOfParticipants()));
            binding.courseTitle.setText(matchCourse.getName());
            if (matchCourse.getImageResource().isEmpty());
            else
                Picasso.get().load(matchCourse.getImageResource()).into(binding.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to show the code for the for `CourseAdapter` class as well

Comment: @Andrew Sure, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, quite often people incorrect construct the Adapter when extending `FragmentStateAdapter` and the viewpager2 is inside another Fragment, that can cause Fragment state issues, but your not using Fragments inside the Viewpager2, so this is not the issue.